# The activity doesn't go back to the previous one (using facebook sdk)

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, fragment

I m using facebook sdk to allow users to log into my app using their facebook account, I m using a fragment that launches an other activity after the login access, and it works fine. The issue is that this activity doesn't come back to the previous one. Facebook SDK 4.0 uses an other activity which is implemented in the SDK and it handles the login, does it have something to do with this issue.
The code I am using:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
    tokenTracker.startTracking();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    if (profile != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayingActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **not** start activity in `onResume()`, because every time you go back to the activity, `onResume()` would be called, then PlayingActivity would be launched if profile is not null.

Move following code to other places,

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
if (profile != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayingActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

[Click to learn more about the Activity Lifecycle.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)